# Facebook Graph API Explorer not showing profile picture, but returns the URL

Tags: image, facebook

We have a Facebook Login in our application, which requests for the logged user profile picture. Suddenly (like 3 days ago) all the profile pictures URL's returns 404 Not Found.

I checked with FB Graph API Explorer, and it returns the picture's URL, but the URL prompts 404 too. For example this image: https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1939024716399864&height=50&width=50&ext=1700986315&hash=AeQj6kUFOZRAqFjPl_I

I tested it with 2 different FB apps, and it's the same. The profile picture URLs gives 404! What's happening?

**GRAPH API EXPLORER FULL DEBUG LOG:**

```
==== Query
  curl -i -X GET \
   "https://graph.facebook.com/v18.0/me?fields=id%2Cpicture&access_token=<access token sanitized>"
==== Access Token Info
  {
    "perms": [
      "email",
      "public_profile"
    ],
    "user_id": 1939024716399864,
    "app_id": 350448015532099
  }
==== Parameters
- Query Parameters


  {
    "fields": "id,picture"
  }
- POST Parameters


  {}
==== Response
  {
    "id": "1939024716399864",
    "picture": {
      "data": {
        "height": 50,
        "is_silhouette": false,
        "url": "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=1939024716399864&height=50&width=50&ext=1700986315&hash=AeQj6kUFOZRAqFjPl_I",
        "width": 50
      }
    },
    "__debug__": {}
  }
==== Debug Information from Graph API Explorer
- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/350448015532099/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cpicture&version=v18.0
```

Comment: Can confirm, and other devs are having the same problem, too - https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/292690177015780/ That one is not an actual bug report though, only a question in their community - I did not find any current bug report for this, so I would suggest you create one.